# How do I fix the Facebook Like metadata on my WordPress site?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

When you Like a post on my WordPress site (www.bryanseacrest.com) it does not correctly populate the right info. How do I go about fixing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

by reading the fine manual - see step 2 of http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/